# Update table based on join query using cacheRowSet?

Tags: java, sql, swing, join

Is it possible to update a junction table by using a join query as refrernce?

I'm using a Jtable to display data from the database. The jtable is loaded on a Jframe using the CacheRowSet

```
jframeconstructor(){
 ...
 CachedRowSet myCachedRowSet = getContentsOfTable();// performs query to load table
 myTableModel = new TheTableModel(myCachedRowSet);// class extends the AbstractTableModel to enable editing 
 jtable.setModel(TheTableModel);
 ...
 }



public CachedRowSet getContentsTable() throws SQLException {
CachedRowSet crs = null;
int [] key={1,2};
try {
  conn = s.getConnection(); //get connection from session
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);//set auto commit to false 
  crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
  crs.setType(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
  crs.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
  crs.setUsername(s.getM_sappuser());
  crs.setPassword(s.getM_spassword());

  if (this.s.getM_database().equals("mysql")) {
    crs.setUrl(s.getM_surl()
            + "?relaxAutoCommit=true");
  } else
  { 
    crs.setUrl(s.getM_surl());

  }


  crs.setCommand("SELECT TICKET_id, line TICKETNumber, item_id, price, Units FROM TICKETLINES ;");
  crs.setKeyColumns(key);
  crs.execute();

} catch (SQLException e) {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
return crs;
```

}

I'm able to edit the product_id from the swing UI using this method in the TheTableModel class:

```
   public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
   System.out.println("Calling setValueAt row " + row + ", column " +    column + ", Value :"+ value);
   try {
   //get the value  and update cacheRowSet
      this.coffeesRowSet.absolute( row + 1 );
      this.coffeesRowSet.updateObject((column + 1), value);
      this.coffeesRowSet.updateRow();
      this.coffeesRowSet.setTableName("TICKETLINES");

      this.coffeesRowSet.acceptChanges(s.getConnection());
      this.coffeesRowSet.refreshRow();
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(CoffeesTableModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
  fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
  }
```

I want the table to display the item names rather than the item id . So if I perform a join on three tables is it possible to edit (update) records from the result table such that they are relected on the juction table?

I mean I have this junction table

```
TICKETLINES
-----------------------------------------------------------
Ticketid    |line number |item_id |description |units price
---+--------+------------+--------+------------+----------- 
   |        |            |        |            |
```

and two other tables

ITEM

---

```
id |name |description |price 
---+-----+------------+-----
   |     |            |     

TICKET
-------------------
id |ticketnumber 
---+-----+--------- 
   |     |
```

After performing an inner join on the tables

```
 SELECT t.ticketnumber AS TicketNumber, i.name as ProductName, tl.price as PRICE, tl.line FROM TICKETS AS T JOIN TICKETLINES AS tl ON tl.TICKET= t.id JOIN ITEM AS i on tl.product=i.id ORDER BY t.ticketnumber,tl.line ;
```

I get a result table, if the first record is

```
ticketnumber ProductName price   line
------------+-----------+-------+-------
   1        | unicorn   |     0 |    0
```

can I change the product name to say "pink elephant" (assuming pink elephant has an id in the item table) on this resultSet and then have my ticketline item_id updated ?  (Actually, I tried it and I got conflicts while sync so I'm just trying to know whether such a thing is actually possible)